# problems with djano-bootstra5. My server won't run

Tags: django-bootstrap4

`I am working Python Crash Course and is making an learning_log app in Django. I have installed django-bootstrap5, but when I put the code in my bsettings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #My apps.
    'learning_logs',
    'accounts',

    #third party apps.
    'django-bootstrap5',#this is the problem
    
    #Default django apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

It worked fin until I tried to style it with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Let's troubleshoot step by step:

1. **Check for Errors:**
   Make sure to look at your terminal or console where you started the Django server. Any errors or traceback messages will provide crucial information about what's going wrong.
2. **Python Environment and Dependencies:**
   Ensure that you are working within the correct Python environment for your Django project. You can use virtual environments to isolate dependencies.
3. **Missing Dependencies:**
   If you've recently added Bootstrap 5, ensure that you have installed it and any other required dependencies. You can install them using `pip`. Run:

   ```
   pip install django-bootstrap5
   ```
4. **Settings Configuration:**
   Verify that you have properly configured Django to use Bootstrap 5. Add `'bootstrap5'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py` file of your Django project:

   ```py
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       # ...
       'bootstrap5',
       # ...
   ]
   ```
5. **Static Files Configuration:**
   Make sure your static files are properly configured. In your `settings.py` file, ensure you have configured the static URL and directories correctly:

   ```py
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
   ```
6. **Migrations:**
   If you've added a new app like Bootstrap 5 and modified models, make sure you've run migrations:

   ```
   python manage.py makemigrations
   python manage.py migrate
   ```
7. **Check URL Configurations:**
   Make sure your URL patterns are correct and pointing to the expected views.
8. **Check Views and Templates:**
   Ensure that your views and templates are correctly implemented and referencing Bootstrap 5 classes properly.
9. **Check HTML Markup:**
   Double-check your HTML markup for any syntax errors, missing tags, or incorrect attribute usage.
10. **Debugging:**
    If the server is not running, it's important to use debugging techniques. Place print statements or use tools like `pdb` to trace the flow of your code.
11. **Logs:**
    Check the Django server logs and your browser's developer console for any error messages or warnings.
12. **Firewall or Port Issues:**
    Ensure that your firewall settings or port configurations are not blocking the server from running or being accessed.

If you've gone through these steps and still can't get your Django server to run, provide more specific details about the errors or issues you're encountering, and I'd be happy to assist you further.